# How to disable Continuity Camera on Mac 1 but use it on Mac 2

Tags: iphone, mac, camera, webcam, continuity

Since updating to MacOS Ventura my Mac prompts me every time I have a video call with enabling Continuity Camera. So I did, with the expectation that I can disable it afterward, because those prompts were bothering me. Unfortunately that doesnt seem possible in the UI on MacOS side. So now I am looking for other ways to disable it.

Since now it's even worse: It automatically connects multiple times to my phone during calls even if I have the built-in webcam selected. This obviously should not happen automatically. Is there a hidden plist or something to change that it stops selecting the Continuity Camera by itself?

I like the feature when I'm at home on Mac 2, but dont want to use it at work on Mac 1 - since I dont have the option to mount or carry my phone around. Therefore the safe solution would be to completely disable it on Mac 1 but leave it as is on Mac 2. I only found the option to disable it on the iPhone for all Macs, but thats not what I want. So I'm looking for an option to kill the Continuity Camera Service on Mac 1. Any ideas?